# Overloaded less then operator returns the opposite boolean value

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I overloaded the less then operator in my `Booking` class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Booking{

private:
long bookingID;

public:
Booking(long bookingID) : bookingID(bookingID){}
long getBookingID(){
    return bookingID;
}

bool operator<(Booking &b){
    return this->bookingID<b.getBookingID();
}
}



int main(){
  Booking* b2 = new Booking(11);
  Booking* b1 = new Booking(2);

  cout << (b1<b2) << endl; // returns 0 (expected 1)
  cout << (b2<b1) << endl; // returns 1 (expected 0)

  return 0;
}
```

What is the issue? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You are comparing pointers, not the values they point to. Try `(*b1<*b2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing pointers, not objects.

What you mean is:

```
Booking b2( 11);
Booking b1( 2);

cout << (b1<b2) << endl; // returns 1, as expected
cout << (b2<b1) << endl; // returns 0, as expected
```

Comment: @Nime why? In the code you posted the only effect is that you leak memory, not something desirable

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am implementing a template sorted linked list with sorted insert. Thats why I need the less then operator. Booking is a base class. I have to use pointers. It is specified in the assignment and  to prevent object slicing...